# Unit test a method of conditionals in jasmine

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm building an angular application and have created a dynamic menu. The menu shows/hides and does other things base on user roles. I'm struggling to write a unit test for my simple methods that pass true/false values to my `*ngIf` query's on the menus `HTML`.

```
private initPilot(
        hasRoleRightsforMenu: boolean,
        highlightForMenu: boolean,
    ) {

        // Operations
        const mainMenu = this.menu.items.find(i => i.id == 'main').menu;
        const menuChild = mainMenu.find(i => i.id == 'child');
        const menuChildTitle = mainMenu.find(i => i.roleView == 'childTitle');

        if (menuChildTitle) {
            menuChildTitle['hidden'] = !hasRoleRightsforMenu;
        }
        if (menuChild) {
            menuChild['hide'] = !hasRoleRightsforMenu;
            menuChild['pilot'] = highlightForMenu;
        }
    }
```

I want to unit test the individual `const` properties and then the conditional below them.

So if the menu with id is found then true, and if they have this role then true/false.

Any help to jasmine UT this would be appreciated. I am very much still learning how to UT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see your method is private and you shouldn't be testing private abstractions, just the overall picture. Also, testing the `const`s will be difficult because you can't have a handle on them from an outside world (testing or another class). What I would do is test the view/HTML after mocking the situation (I assume `this.menu`).

Something along the lines of:

```
it('should show menu XYZ if ABC', () => {
  component.menu = [{...}, {...}] // mock ABC situation.
  fixture.detectChanges(); // make change detection kick in to see the updated view
  // The following line grabs a handle on the view and we are querying for an element
  // with an id of xyz. You can put any CSS selector there and it should be assigned to
  // XYZMenu if found. It returns an object and it has a nativeElement property which is
  // the HTMLElement itself. It returns null if nothing was found.
  const XYZMenu = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#xyz'));
  expect(XYZMenu).toBeTruthy();
});
```

[Angular 2 App Testing, how to access and operate on html elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45802387/angular-2-app-testing-how-to-access-and-operate-on-html-elements)

Something like that might help you but it can be overwhelming. I would look through the docs and go step by step in each property/line and understand what it is doing.